# Restarting IIS Fails?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-8

We have a C# ASP.NET 3.5 web site with hundreds of .cs files in AppCode. When we make a change to the files in AppCode, we often (but not always) get this type of error message with each page load:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0042: Unexpected error creating debug information file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\626a8115\4c03f3b6\App_Code.PDB' -- 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\626a8115\4c03f3b6\App_Code.pdb: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

In the past, restarting IIS via IIS > Manage Server > Restart has been sufficient to clear this error. Ideally, we wouldn't have to restart IIS, but it works.

Now, though, IIS won't restart. We get an error message of "Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed." Clicking Restart again gives "Cannot stop W3SVC service on computer '.'" We have to restart the entire server to return IIS to functioning.

Any ideas for why IIS won't restart anymore, or why we have to restart IIS in the first place?

Comment: It seems like you are deploying without stopping the running services. The service may have exclusive locks on the files you are trying to replace and that is why you are running into these issues. Also, is this a development server you intend to debug? If you deploy with release config the default shouldn't deploy with a pdb file since it is typically only necessary for debug.

Comment: https://forums.iis.net/t/1239061.aspx?IISRESET+results+in+W3SVC+stuck+in+stopping+status+after+July+2018+patches

Comment: Any specific reason changing the source code directly on the server. It is preferable to publish your application first and then deploy with release configuration